# Powershell remove a range of lines from a text file

Tags: powershell

I have a text file that contains this

```
REV#           CUST REV#                                    
BARREL. ADD SLIDE TO CAST THE 1.03 & .413
DIAMETERS TO REV G                               
PART #   LED-4506-X  REF. JOB#  13445   
SHIP:  COLL    SHIP TO ADDRESS: SEE PO
QUESTIONER: NO  Penalty:  NO  QTY: 1
DUE DATE: 12/28/18       
P.O. TOTAL AMOUNT $1.00     TERMS: N/30
QUOTE: WRITTEN PULLED: YES 
HOURS:  100     MATERIAL: 1,000.00     RATE:    82
TYPE: DIDI   FOREMAN:    MP    SALESPERSON: RO      
DETAILS:   YES  / ENG     GANTT CHART:      YES
```

I need to strip everything after `SHIP`

I know I can remove each line with something like this

```
(Get-Content C:\MyFile.txt) |
Where { $_ -notmatch "SHIP" } |
Where { $_ -notmatch "QUESTIONER:" } |
Where { $_ -notmatch "DUE DATE:" } |
Where { $_ -notmatch "P.O." }|
Where { $_ -notmatch "QUOTE:" }|
Where { $_ -notmatch "HOURS:" }|
Where { $_ -notmatch "TYPE:" }|
Where { $_ -notmatch "DETAILS:" }|
Set-Content C:\MyFile.txt
```

But occasionally I will have random lines of data that will be in there that I need to remove as well say line this

```
REV#           CUST REV#                                    
BARREL. ADD SLIDE TO CAST THE 1.03 & .413
DIAMETERS TO REV G                               
PART #   LED-4506-X  REF. JOB#  13445   
SHIP:  COLL    SHIP TO ADDRESS: SEE PO
QUESTIONER: NO  Penalty:  NO  QTY: 1
DUE DATE: 12/28/18,
12/29/18,
12/30/18         
P.O. TOTAL AMOUNT $1.00     TERMS: N/30
QUOTE: WRITTEN PULLED: YES 
HOURS:  100     MATERIAL: 1,000.00     RATE:    82
SOME OTHER INFORMATION
TYPE: DIDI   FOREMAN:    MP    SALESPERSON: RO      
DETAILS:   YES  / ENG     GANTT CHART:      YES
```

Where there will be extra dates or other information that my above code will not catch. How can I do a range of lines from `SHIP` all the way to the end of the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following (be sure to have a backup of `C:\MyFile.txt`, given that you're overwriting the file in place):

```
((Get-Content -Raw C:\MyFile.txt) -csplit '\r?\nSHIP:')[0] |
  Set-Content C:\MyFile.txt
```

This reads your file in full `Get-Content -Raw` and then splits (`-csplit`, case-sensitively) the resulting multi-line string by a line that starts with `SHIP:`

The resulting array's 1st element (`[0]`) is therefore the contents of the file up to, but excluding, the `SHIP:` line.

Answer (score 0):

If the content you want is always on the first 4 lines you can just do this:

```
(Get-Content C:\file.txt)[0..3] | set-content C:\outfile.txt
```