# Powershell. Remove Specific Line Numbers

Tags: powershell

We have multiple text files in a folder that needs editing. The text files are Multi-Stage Azure Pipelines as code (.yaml) for Azure DevOps, that we need to update. We have specific line numbers that need to be cut, for example we need to cut out lines 54-68 from 30 files, but keep the rest of the code. An example of such lines:

```
- stage: DeployWebApps
  variables:
  - group: Environment1
  jobs:
  - job: DeployWebApps
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    - task: AzureFileCopy@3
      displayName: 'Copy ARM Template'
      inputs:
        SourcePath: 'DevOps\IaC\WebApps.json'
        azureSubscription: Development Subscription Service Connection'
        Destination: 'AzureBlob'
        storage: 'xxx'
        ContainerName: 'armtemplates'
        outputStorageUri: 'artifactsLocation'
        outputStorageContainerSasToken: 'artifactsLocationSasToken'
        sasTokenTimeOutInMinutes: '240'
```

We would like to use the approach I described because line 56:

```
  - group: Environment1
```

is different in each file while the rest of the lines are the same. Regex seem to be overkill that is more difficult to write than PowerShell for such case and doesn’t solve the problem of replacing lines in multiple files.

The best approach I found is in an answer here
[Powershell remove a range of lines from a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53785506/powershell-remove-a-range-of-lines-from-a-text-file)

> If the content you want is always on the first 4 lines you can just do
> this:

```
(Get-Content C:\file.txt)[0..3] | set-content C:\outfile.txt
```

This script removes everything except lines 1-4. How can I remove only lines 54-68 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell Core (v7+), `Select-Object` has a `-SkipIndex` parameter that allows skipping multiple lines using the pipeline.

```
Get-Content -Path file.txt | Select-Object -SkipIndex (53..67) |
    Set-Content output.txt
```

Note that `-SkipIndex` skips the actual index number (starts at `0`) rather than the number of lines as required by `-Skip`.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done as follow:

```
[string[]]$array = Get-Content -Path C:\file.txt

$array[0..52] + $array[68 ..($array.length -1)] | Set-Content C:\outfile.txt
```

Comment: You may need to make this `($array.length -1)`.

Comment: yes you are right, although it works without the -1 but as an accurate answer i shoud make the lenght -1, i modified it, thanks.

Comment: @MahmoudMoawad It works without `length-1` because strict mode is off. You never know what mode the user's environment may be.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Thanks for pointing this out, I didn't knew that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an odd solution that uses the hidden readcount property returned by get-content.

```
# get-content c:\file.txt | select *
get-content c:\file.txt | where readcount -notin (54..68) | 
  set-content c:\outfile.txt
```